# Name of the dish Mr. Bean orders on his birthday and dislikes?

Tags: mr-bean

There is an episode of *Mr. Bean* in which he goes to a busy restaurant on his birthday for a treat and orders some unfamiliar dish to fit his budget.

But soon he finds it disgusting and tries a variety of ways to get rid of that like hiding it inside a vase, some bread and a woman's handbag.

He somehow makes a waiter trip and fall on the ground messing up his table. He then blames the waiter and shows all the places food has gotten into. Feeling convinced, the manager re-orders the same dish for Mr. Bean and all his efforts go in vain.

So what dish it was?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In The Return of Mr. Bean, he orders Steak Tartare.

> Steak tartare is a meat dish made from finely chopped or minced raw beef or horsemeat. It is often served with onions, capers and seasonings, sometimes with a raw egg yolk, and often on rye bread. -Wikipedia

This is like the Mr. Bean Holiday Movie and in that it was a sea food platter, including raw oysters. Hilarity ensues,  especially the part of the handbag.

Of course it could be a different episode as I'm sure they had the same joke multiple times.